# After installing Android App on device, app could not recognize database. 

Tags: android

Apps runs fine on emulator, but the same does not on device(Samsung S5670). Its showing that the database is empty. 
Should i need to upload databases separately or it is embedded in apk itself.
I have also check the File explorer in DDMS -> "Data" section could not find any data in it.

Do i need to make any other setting on device

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't write the required SQLite helper class that initializes your database. Somehow once you managed to create the correct database on the emulator, so it works on that. Try uninstalling your app completely from you emulator, reinstall it, and see if it works. Only updating you app doesn't remove data associated with it on the device, so i doesn't affect your database, hence you need to uninstall.

If it stops working on you emu too, then you need to go look into your SQLite helper class.